# Disable/Enable HtmlSelect based on checkbox checked in javascript and asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, select, checkbox

Here is the situation. I have a htmlselect control that when loaded needs to be initially enabled or disabled based upon something that is true or not from the database query. Then I need the user to be able to click on a checkbox to disable or enable the same htmlselect control, ALL without a postback.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using javascript and code-behind I was able to get this to work. Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Should be something like that:

```
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="document.getElementById('idOfSelect').disabled=(this.checked)?false:true">
```

Comment: That is all good and everything, but the control needs to be disabled or enabled automatically on screen load depending on a certain switch coming from t he database query

Comment: I think in asp.net it should be possible to set there an attribute "disabled" depending on your condition.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to generate the HTML dynamically at runtime, either by generating it from your server code or using a template.  Use the code Dr.Molle suggested above, and insert an `enabled` attribute for the checkbox / disabled style for the `SELECT` based on the result from the database query:

```
<INPUT type-"checkbox" checked ...>
<SELECT ...>
```

if it is supposed to be enabled or

```
<INPUT type-"checkbox" ...>
<SELECT disabled ...>
```

if it is not.

Unfortunately, you can't combine the HTML generation to set the initial state and the dynamic change based on user interaction, unless you use a really sophisticated web framework.

Putting it all together, using a common templating convention, your HTML template might look like this:

```
<INPUT type="checkbox" ${mySelectIsInitallyEnabled ? "checked" : ""} onclick="document.getElementById('mySelect').disabled=(this.checked)?false:true">
<SELECT id="mySelect" ${mySelectIsInitallyEnabled ? "" : "disabled"}>

    <!-- options ... -->

</SELECT>
```